# What distribution to use for continuous left skewed dependent variable in generalized linear mixed models?

Tags: r, regression, distributions, multiple-regression, biostatistics

I conducted a study to compare the effectiveness of different fungicides in controlling a plant disease. I assessed disease severity as the response variable, which is measured on a 0-5 scale. A rating of 0 indicates healthy plants, while ratings 1-5 correspond to increasing levels of infection (1: less than 20%, 5: greater than 80%). The maximum possible infection level is 100%. The unique values in my response variable are: 0.0, 1.5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 2.5, 1.0, 4.0, and 5.

The experimental design follows a randomized complete block design (RCBD) with four blocks. Each block represents a different level of disease material used to induce plant infection. Additionally, I assessed the disease severity at three different dates, resulting in a time series dataset.

I want to know which distribution would be appropriate to analyze this data?

Raw data distribution of response variable

[image]

Here is the histogram of residuals

```
m <- glmmTMB::glmmTMB(mean_severity_trt ~ block + (1|assessment_number), family = gaussian, data= dat)

summary(m)

hist(residuals(m))
```

I don't know why I got negative values

[image]

Comment: In the absence of information about the distribution of outcomes given a set of predictor values, ordinal regression is appropriate. That's the case whether the underlying data are truly continuous or are restricted to a small set of values. The R [`ordinal` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ordinal) can handle mixed models.